# Connection error with Google Drive API? NETWORK_ERROR

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I get the following error:

[GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: ELLIDED:1679352783, App: com.dreamappsstore.googledrive_demo, Service: oauth2:email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file openid profile

Without doing any changes to my code, I started to get this error in my Android emulator when trying to connect to Google Drive API.

I tried to google for why this could happen but did not find anything useful...

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was related to being connected to a VPN. When I disconnected my VPN, everything worked again.